# UISearchBar on UITableView with scope bar resizes itself over other UI items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

Ok, so I've got a UITableView below a UISearchBar. Above that is just some UILables and UIButtons and then the UINavigationBar.

The UISearchBar has the scope bar enabled. Whenever I tap on the search bar I get the following odd behaviour (I've got the on screen keyboard disabled but the focus is in the UISearchBar text field):

[image: Odd search bar behaviour]

Where as normally it looks like this:

[image: How it should look]

It's really frustrating and I can't work out why it's happening. Has anybody experienced anything similar and found a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your search bar and its scope in the nib file.

Comment: how did you add the search bar and the header labels to the `UITableView`?

Comment: The UITableView and UISearchBar are separate entities, I've just set the UISearchBar's delegate to the UITableView. the header labels are just UILabels added onto the UIView. In the Storyboard file the UISearchBar fits in fine but doesn't show the Scope bar.

Comment: Try adding your search bar below the header view in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bodge, but it's the best I could come up with. I just put the following in viewWillAppear and then manually created a background image of 44px high and put it behind the UISearchBar on the storyboard.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {

        for(UIView *subView2 in subview.subviews){

            for(UIView *subView3 in subView2.subviews){
                if ([[[subView3  class] description] isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarBackground"]) {
                   [subView3 removeFromSuperview];
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```